# Opening MobileFirst Console throws errors (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-console

I'am using Eclipse JUNO 4.2.2 for JAVA EE Developers with IBM Mobile First 6.3 Developer Edition.

I am also using Java 1.7 and the ADT plug-in in Eclipse.
My problem is when i try to visualize my App in the MobileFirt Console i have an error that says

```
Server error. Contact the server administrator.
```

And i have the following logs in my eclipse console:

```
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\Aokiji\IBM%20Workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_108\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
C:\Users\Aokiji\IBM%20Workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_108\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] C:\Users\Aokiji\IBM%20Workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_108\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
C:\Users\Aokiji\IBM%20Workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\73\data\cache\com.ibm.ws.app.manager_108\.cache\WEB-INF\lib\ibm_web20_wink_no_abdera_no_jackson-1.1.0.0-20110422.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
[ERROR   ] Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet 
                                                                                                               ManagementServlet
                                                                                                               WorklightServices
                                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.wink.common.internal.i18n.Messages
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.initAlternateShortcutMap(DeploymentConfiguration.java:386)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.DeploymentConfiguration.init(DeploymentConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getDeploymentConfiguration(RestServlet.java:202)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there are unexplained Mobilefirst Studio errors, such as yours, it is typically best to:

1. Create a new workspace
2. Import the project
3. Re-build

If it fails still you should install the latest 6.3 plugin. You can obtain it from the following location: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/#past-releases

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you